# Why does a non-static field not act as a GC root?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, member, gc-roots

As I know static fields (along with Threads, local variables and method arguments, JNI references) act as GC roots.

I cannot provide a link that would confirm this, but I have read a lot of articles on it.

Why can't a non-static field act as a GC root?

Comment: Because a non static field goes out of life when its owning objects goes away!?

Comment: If non-static fields acted as GC roots, and static fields acted as GC roots, and local variables acted as GC roots, which objects would the GC collect?

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis objects which acts as GC root cannot be collected?

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis I thought that GC roots just point where we start search objects  to collect

Comment: @gstackoverflow then the object containing the field is strictly more rootish than the field itself.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Do you mean that somewhere exists fabric method that will create object which will contain this field?

Comment: @gstackoverflow He means what he said. If there wasn't a way to create the containing object there would be no way to create the contained field, so there would be nothing to GC in any case. Your questions are rather peculiar.

Comment: You can't *have* a non static field without an object containing it.  That object is a strictly better GC root than the field would be.

Answer (score 6):

First off, we need to be sure we're on the same page as to what a tracing garbage collection algorithm does in its mark phase.

At any given moment, a tracing GC has a number of objects that are known to be alive, in the sense that they are reachable by the running program as it stands right now. *The main step of mark phrase involves following the non-static fields of those objects to find more objects, and those new objects will now also be known to be alive.* This step is repeated recursively until no new alive objects are found by traversing the existing live objects. All objects in memory not proved live are considered dead. (The GC then moves to the next phase, which is called the sweep phase. We don't care about that phase for this answer.)

Now this alone is not enough to execute the algorithm. In the beginning, the algorithm has no objects that it knows to be alive, so it can't start following anyone's non-static fields. We need to specify a set of objects that are considered known to be alive from the start. We choose those objects axiomatically, in the sense that they don't come from a previous step of the algorithm -- they come from outside. Specifically, they come from the semantics of the language. Those objects are called roots.

In a language like Java, there are two sets of objects that are definite GC roots. Anything that is accessible by a local variable that's still in scope is obviously reachable (within its method, which still hasn't returned), therefore it's alive, therefore it's a root. Anything that is accessible through a static field of a class is also obviously reachable (from anywhere), therefore it's alive, therefore it's a root.

But if non-static fields were considered roots as well, what would happen?

Say you instantiate an `ArrayList<E>`. Inside, that object has a non-static field that points to an `Object[]` (the backing array that represents the storage of the list). At some point, a GC cycle starts. In the mark phase, the `Object[]` is marked as alive because it is pointed to by the `ArrayList<E>` private non-static field. The `ArrayList<E>` is not pointed to by anything, so it fails to be considered alive. Thus, in this cycle, the `ArrayList<E>` is destroyed while the backing `Object[]` survives. Of course, at the next cycle, the `Object[]` also dies, because it is not reachable by any root. But why do this in two cycles? If the `ArrayList<E>` was dead in the first cycle and if `Object[]` is used only by a dead object, shouldn't the `Object[]` also be considered dead in the same move, to save time and space?

That's the point here. If we want to be maximally efficient (in the context of a tracing GC), we need to get rid of as many dead objects as possible in a single GC.

To do that, a non-static field should keep an object alive only if the enclosing object (the object that contains the field) *has been proved to be alive.* By contrast, *roots are objects we call alive axiomatically* (without proof) in order to kick-start the algorithm's marking phase. It is in our best interest to limit the latter category to the bare minimum that doesn't break the running program.

For example, say you have this code:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.gc();
    }

    public void test() {
        Integer a = 1;
        bar.counter++; //access to the non-static field
    }
}

class Bar {
    int counter = 0;
}
```

- When the garbage collection starts, we get one root that's the local variable `Foo foo`. That's it, that's our only root.
- We follow the root to find the instance of `Foo`, which is marked as alive and then we attempt to find its non-static fields. We find one of them, the `Bar bar` field.
- We follow the fields to find the instance of `Bar`, which is marked as alive and then we attempt to find its non-static fields. We find that it contains no more fields that are reference types, so the GC doesn't need to bother for that object anymore.
- Since we can't get find new alive objects in this round of recursion, the mark phase can end.

Alternatively:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        Integer a = 1;
        bar.counter++; //access to the non-static field
        System.gc();
    }
}

class Bar {
    int counter = 0;
}
```

- When the garbage collection starts, the local variable `Integer a` is a root and the `Foo this` reference (the implicit reference that all non-static methods get) is also a root. The local variable `Foo foo` from `main` is also a root because `main` hasn't gone out of scope yet.
- We follow the root to find the instance of `Integer` and instance of `Foo` (we find one of these objects twice, but this doesn't matter for the algorithm), which are marked as alive and then we attempt to follow their non-static fields. Let's say the instance of `Integer` has no more fields to class instances. The instance of `Foo` gives us one `Bar` field.
- We follow the field to find the instance of `Bar`, which is marked as alive and then we attempt to find its non-static fields. We find that it contains no more fields that are reference types, so the GC doesn't need to bother for that object anymore.
- Since we can't get find new alive objects in this round of recursion, the mark phase can end.

Comment: But if inside method I use non-static field? Is It considered as local variable?

Comment: pasted to the end of your topic

Comment: I've added an explanation for your example.

Comment: @gstackoverflow If you use a non-static field inside a method it is considered as a non-static field.

Answer (score 3):

A non static field has a reference held by the instance that contains it, so it cannot be a GC root on its own right.