# PhantomReference with null queue

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize, finalization, phantom-reference

Java allow to write:

```
new PhantomReference(new Object(), null)
```

At this case `new Object()` will be collected?

As I understand, phantom reference is alternative of `finalize()`  method usage.

And after appearing reference in queue, I need to do some additional actions and then run `clear()`

java doc stays:

> It is possible to create a phantom reference with a null queue, but
>   such a reference is completely useless: Its get method will always
>   return null and, since it does not have a queue, it will never be
>   enqueued

What does mean if it will never be enqueued?

As I understand it means that after finalize method invocation rerference will not be added to the referenceQueue. Thus it may lead to:
1. object memory will be cleared at once
2. Object memory will not be cleared

which case correct?

Comment: What is your actual question here? Can you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599069/have-you-ever-used-phantom-reference-in-any-project for example?

Comment: And the javadoc for that PhantomReference ctor clearly says: *It is possible to create a phantom reference with a null queue, but such a reference is completely useless: Its get method will always return null and, since it does not have a queue, it will never be enqueued.* So, yes, that newly created Object is thus subject to garbage collection.

Comment: @GhostCat, Why do you think so? how can we check this? I don't see causal relationship

Comment: Passing that newly created object X into a PhantomReference ... should not make X a "live" object. There is no reason why the GC should be prevented from collecting it. And as the PhantomReference doesnt have a queue for X either ... I assume the only thing that can happen to X is: being garbage collected the next time the GC runs. And I agree with UNIQUEorn - no idea where you want to go with this question. What is the problem you intend to solve?

Comment: @GhostCat but if we pass queue to constructor, queue hold the reference and it prevent for object to be collected?

Comment: Not at all. The links clearly explain that: PhantomRefernces do not prevent gargabe collection. They are simply a mechanism to **understand** when the GC does its work. You can say: "give me a shoulder tap when X goes away". And then you get a shoulder tap; and decide what to do about that. Thats it.

Comment: @GhostCat looks like it is correct for weak/soft references nut incorect for phantom reference

Comment: And what makes you think so?

Comment: @GhostCat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html

Comment: @GhostCat **Unlike soft and weak references, phantom references are not automatically cleared by the garbage collector as they are enqueued. An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable.**

Comment: @UNIQUEorn, I merely learn/investigate java deeper

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-refs/

Comment: @gstackoverflow: that IBM article contradicts the documentation and actual implementation behavior of Oracle’s JRE in several aspects. Don’t count on it…

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I noted that you have several gc related questions that are still open, i.e. [q1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41378933), [q2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41366036), [q3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41378606) and [q4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41919394). So it would be great to know whether there are still things unclear or whether these issues aren’t relevant to you anymore. I’m thinking about adding an answer here, especially as it might contradict the most of the comments, but if you don’t need it anymore, you may remove the question instead.

Comment: @Holger I will be happy if you answer these questions

Comment: @gstackoverflow: the other questions have answers, two of them even have an answer of mine. If they are not satisfying, you should add clarifying comments to address what’s missing. Otherwise, you may accept an answer (doesn’t need to be mine ;-). I added an answer to this question; it became a bit bigger than I thought, but that’s a *really interesting* topic…

Comment: @Holger I will see all answers tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, as you noticed yourself, a `PhantomReference` is not automatically cleared. This implies that as long as you keep a strong reference to the `PhantomReference`, the referent will stay phantom reachable. As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) says: “*An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable.*”

However, considering when an object is unreachable (now I’m talking about the “phantom references themselves”) can lead to many surprises. Especially as it’s very likely that the reference object, not providing useful operations, will not be subsequently touched anymore.

Since the `PhantomReference` without a queue will never be enqueued and its `get()` method will always return `null`, it is indeed not useful.

So why does the constructor allows to construct such a useless object? Well, [the documentation of the very first version (1.2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20010414031740/http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html#PhantomReference(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)) states that it will throw a `NullPointerException` if the queue is `null`. This statement persists until 1.4, then [Java 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html#PhantomReference(T,%20java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)) is the first version containing the statement that you *can* construct a `PhantomReference` without a queue, despite being useless. My guess is, that it always inherited the super class’ behavior of allowing a `null` queue, contradicting the documentation, and it was noticed so late, that the decision was made to stay compatible and adapt the documentation rather than changing the behavior.

---

The question, even harder to answer, is why a `PhantomReference` isn’t automatically cleared. The documentation only says that a phantom reachable object will remain so, which is the consequence of not being cleared, but doesn’t explain why this has any relevance.

This question has been [brought up on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048767/2711488), but the answer isn’t really satisfying. It says “to allow performing cleanup **before** an object is garbage collected”, which might even match the mindset of whoever made that design decision, but since the cleanup code can’t access the object, it has no relevance whether it is executed before or after the object is reclaimed. As said above, since this rule depends on the reachability of the `PhantomReference` object, which is subject to optimizing code transformations, it might be even the case that the object is reclaimed together with the `PhantomReference` instance before the cleanup code completes, without anyone noticing.

I also found a similar [question on the HotSpot developer mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2013-May/007384.html) back in 2013 which also lacks an answer.

There is the enhancement request [JDK-8071507](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071507) to change that behavior and clear `PhantomReference`s just like the others, which has the status “fixed” for Java 9, and indeed, [its documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) now states that they are cleared like any other reference.

This, unfortunately implies that the answer at the beginning of my post will be wrong starting with Java 9. Then, `new PhantomReference(new Object(), null)` will make the newly created `Object` instance immediately eligible for garbage collection, regardless of whether you keep a strong reference to the `PhantomReference` instance or not.

Comment: nice research. Thus since java 9 PhantomReference will not finalize alternative (because semantic "before clearing")  will be violated ? what about back compatibility?

Comment: As I tried to say, the “before clearing” semantic never had any use. The phantom reference never allows accessing the referent, hence, it doesn’t matter whether the referent still exists in memory or not. Keeping it in memory longer than necessary was a waste of resources. That’s why several applications (including mine) always used `WeakReference` instead, which eliminates the need to collect the referent twice, thus being potentially more efficient. For objects without a custom `finalize()` method, there is no semantic difference. Starting with Java 9, the differences are even less.