# How WeakHashMap works under the hood

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references, weakhashmap

I invesigate WeakHashMap ource code to have more knowledge about `WeakReference`

I have found that entry looks like this:

```
private static class Entry<K,V> extends WeakReference<Object> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        V value;
        final int hash;
        Entry<K,V> next;

        /**
         * Creates new entry.
         */
        Entry(Object key, V value,
              ReferenceQueue<Object> queue,
              int hash, Entry<K,V> next) {
            super(key, queue);
            this.value = value;
            this.hash  = hash;
            this.next  = next;
        }
        ...
```

Thus when we create new entry we invoke `super(key, queue);`. It is `WeakReference` constructor. As far I understand **after** object will be collected by GC the new reference(I believe it should be reference on `key`) will be appeared in the queue.

Also I have noticed method which invokes on each operation:

```
    /**
     * Expunges stale entries from the table.
     */
    private void expungeStaleEntries() {
        for (Object x; (x = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Entry<K,V> e = (Entry<K,V>) x;
                int i = indexFor(e.hash, table.length);

                Entry<K,V> prev = table[i];
                Entry<K,V> p = prev;
                while (p != null) {
                    Entry<K,V> next = p.next;
                    if (p == e) {
                        if (prev == e)
                            table[i] = next;
                        else
                            prev.next = next;
                        // Must not null out e.next;
                        // stale entries may be in use by a HashIterator
                        e.value = null; // Help GC
                        size--;
                        break;
                    }
                    prev = p;
                    p = next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Looks like we get  `(Entry<K,V>)` from queue.  I don't know how to explain this(**first question**).
this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    StringBuilder AAA = new StringBuilder();
    ReferenceQueue queue = new ReferenceQueue();
    WeakReference weakRef = new WeakReference(AAA, queue);
    AAA = null;
    System.gc();
    Reference removedReference = queue.remove();
    System.out.println(removedReference.get());
}
```

always outputs null, because object already collected by GC

Also for me it was strange that we can have reference on Object which was already collected by GC. Actually I expect that reference should appear in queue but I could not read something meaningful because object already collected(**second question**).

Comment: @downvoter, I added explicitly in text things I want to clarify

Comment: have you looked at other SO questions relating ReferenceQueue?

Comment: @the8472 I didn't see related tag

Comment: not a tag, just search for *ReferenceQueue*

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like we get (Entry) from queue. I don't know how to explain this

`queue.poll()` gives you the reference instances you put into the queue through the reference constructor. In this case it's `Entry<K,V> extends WeakReference<Object>`.

> Actually I expect that reference should appear in queue but I could not read something meaningful because object already collected

You get the `Reference` object itself which you can use to do some cleanup, either through subclassing or by associating it with additional data e.g. through an auxiliary `Map`. The referee you can obtain through `get` while it is still alive is not relevant, the `Reference` object itself is.

Comment: why do I put **Entry<K,V>** ?

Comment: How gc understand that key related with Entry rather than just WeakReference ?

Comment: Those are new questions. I suggest reading the javadocs or studying other examples relating to `ReferenceQueue` on SO, there are much simpler examples than `WeakHashMap`

Comment: Simpler examples is clear for me. I don't understand with inheritance

Answer (score 0):

The queue returns the very reference object, you have created before. So with your example code, after executing

```
Reference removedReference = queue.remove();
```

the expression `removedReference == weakRef` would evaluate to `true`, as that’s the only reference object you’ve ever created. With this test, you can already conclude that the object formerly referenced by `AAA` has been collected, due to the identity of the reference object, so you already read “something meaningful”.

If you want to associate more information with it, a viable way is to create a subclass of `WeakReference`, which is exactly what `WeakHashMap.Entry` is about. In its constructor, it calls `super(key, queue);`, which is not different to your expression `new WeakReference(AAA, queue)`, the first argument specifies the weakly referenced object.

So the garbage collector will enqueue the specialized `WeakReference`, i.e. `Entry`, object if its referent (the `key`) has become unreachable. At this point, the key can’t be retrieved anymore, i.e. its `get()` method will return `null`, but the method `expungeStaleEntries()` isn’t interested in the key anyway. It wants to remove the `Entry` instance from the table, allowing the garbage collector to reclaim the `Entry` instance itself and possibly the referenced value, if there are no other reference to it. It helps that this subclass has remembered the previously calculated hash code, so the map doesn’t need to search linearly.

Answer (score 0):

When a `ReferenceQueue` is polled it will return a `Reference` object to the referent. The enqueue operation is done by `Reference#enqueue` which adds `this` to the queue. Thus, for `WeakReference`, since it extends `Reference` the return value can be cast to `WeakReference`.

So, in the `WeakHashMap` implementation since the `Entry<K, V>` extends `WeakReference` the return value for poll can be cast to `Entry<K, V>` as it is a subclass of `WeakReference` which is a subclass of `Reference`. In other words, the `Reference#enqueue` will add to queue `this` thus in the `WeakHashMap` implementation it will enqueue the instance of `Entry<K, V>`.

Do note that the class `Entry<K, V>` doesn't refer to key since it will lead to strong reference and thus GC will not finalize it. It only keeps the hash so that query for `get` can be executed under normal circumstances i.e. when the key is strongly referenced.